# Flatten for ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

How do I flatten a list of the form

```
{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9},...}
```

to put it in the form

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9},...}
```

required to use ListDensityPlot? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can also use `Interpolation` and `DensityPlot`

Comment: You can do it with `ReplaceAll`. Like so: `data /. {{a_, b_}, c_} -> {a, b, c}`

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten[#] & /@ {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}}

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

The above Flattens each sublist.

Mr. Hanlon makes the good point that:

```
Flatten /@ {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{4, 5}, 6}, {{7, 8}, 9}}
```

works as well.

Comment: Since single-argument functions do not need an explicit argument when mapped, `Flatten /@ list` also works.